# how plt.show() gets the parameters here?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, data-science

from the book data-science for supply chain forecast by Nicolas Vandeput
first chap, in this code snippet plt.show() dispaly data but I can not find at what point the arguments passed to it.

```
from chap_01_05_moving_average_function import (
    moving_average,
)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = [28, 19, 18, 13, 19, 16, 19, 18, 13, 16, 16, 11, 18, 15, 13, 15, 13, 11, 13, 10, 12]
df = moving_average(d)
print(df)

df[["Demand", "Forecast"]].plot()

df.index.name = "Periods"
print("index", df.index.name)
df[["Demand", "Forecast"]].plot(
    figsize=(8, 3), title="Moving average", ylim=(0, 30), style=["-", "--"]
)

plt.show()
```

this is chap_01_05_moving_average_function.py:

```
# page 5 - moving average

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def moving_average(d, extra_periods=1, n=3):
    d = np.array(d)
    cols = len(d)
    d = np.append(d, [np.nan] * extra_periods)
    f = np.full(cols + extra_periods, np.nan)

    for t in range(n, cols + 1):
        f[t] = np.mean(d[t - n : t])

    f[cols + 1 :] = f[t]

    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"Demand": d, "Forecast": f, "Error": d - f})

    return df


# numpy - add arrays
ts = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
ts2 = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60])
print(ts + ts2)

# numpy - list

alist = [1, 2, 3]
alistmean = np.mean(alist)
print(alistmean)

# slicing

alist = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"]
print(alist[1])

anarray = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(anarray[0])

# slicing - start:end

alist = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"]
print(alist[1:])

anarray = np.array([1, 2, 3])
print(anarray[:1])

# slicing - negative

alist = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"]
print(alist[-1])

print(alist[:-1])
```

I am new to python I dont know if there is an implicit way of passing parameters

Comment: [`pyplot.show`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html). There are no parameters, it just shows the result of the previous line: `df[["Demand", "Forecast"]].plot(...)`.

Comment: `plt.show()` displays the plot that was created by `df[["Demand", "Forecast"]].plot()`

Comment: I understand that it l displays the plot. But how it does it read the plot there is no association between the two. df comes from panda and plt comes from matplotlib.pyplot. Does plt read the whole file it is being called from and find panda plot and display it?